# Bluemix: Is it possible to connect to GitHub from within the Bluemix dashboard

Tags: github, ibm-cloud

If I create an app from boilerplate, may I host that code on GitHub instead of Jazz Git from within the dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

If you store your code in a Git repository that is hosted by IBM Bluemix DevOps Services (clicking on "Add Git"), you can work with code in a Git terminal or in a web IDE. If you already have another Git repo, you can use it with a DevOps Services project, but you need to do the following:

1. Go to DevOps Services. On the My Projects page, click CREATE PROJECT.
2. Name your project.
3. Click Create a new repository.
4. Click Create a Git repo on Bluemix.
   Note: Do not select the Initialize the repository with a README and license template check box.
5. Select or clear the other project options as needed.
6. Click CREATE.
7. Open a command-line window and change to your Git repo directory.
8. Push the contents of the repo by typing these commands:

`git remote add new_repo https://hub.jazz.net/git/your_alias/project_name
 git push -u new_repo master`

For more information please take a look at [IBM Bluemix DevOps Services - Git source control](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/git/#existing_git_repository)

Answer (score 1):

you need first to push your code to github and then you can create a webhook from Bluemix DevOps interface (https://hub.jazz.net/) to your existing github project by creating a new Bluemix DevOps project. In that way your code is on GitHub but you can still use the DevOps Bluemix pipeline.